# PHP parsing JSON string

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I'm having great trouble passing some information from my Angularjs code to my PHP code for processing.

JS

Controller

```
var dataString = '{"round": {"number": 1,"drops": [{"pos": "0","cust": 1025}]}}';
dropService.updateDrops(dataString)
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
})
```

Service

```
updateDrops : function(drops) {
        return $http({
            url: "/app/php/update_rounds.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: drops,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
    }
```

PHP

```
$dropString = $_POST;

$dropArray = json_decode($_POST);
$a = $dropArray->{"round"}->{"number"};

echo "Round = ".$a;
```

What I expect to see on the console is

Round = 1

but what I get is

Round =

Obviously something is going screwy. However if I replace

```
$dropString = $_POST;
```

with

```
$dropString = '{"round": {"number": 1,"drops": [{"pos": "0","cust": 1025}]}}';
```

everything works out just fine so I know that the PHP will work if I can just get the right data to it. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `$_POST` is a PHP array with all posted values. Try `var_dump($_POST);` to check which your data uses or provide one in your AJAX request that you use specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_POST is an array of key=>value pairs

You're looking for the entire POST BODY as a string. Use this:

```
$dropString = http_get_request_body();
```

Edit: If that doesn't work, use

```
$dropString = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Might want to make a note that this is only available in `pecl_http`, otherwise just use `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Answer (score 0):

This is my working example with use Angular,PHP and MySQL. I use JSON to communicate between controller and PHP dataset file.
[my example on GitHub](https://github.com/mirekh/angular_php_mysql)

Start reading from: [controllers.js](https://github.com/mirekh/angular_php_mysql/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js)

Most interesting line (in this case) is in file 'controllers.js' line 54-63.
Listed bellow:

```
$scope.updateTable = function() {
    $http({
        url: 'phpcode/dataset1.php',
        method: 'GET',
        params: {table: $scope.choice, index: $scope.index, viewingSize: $scope.viewingSize, sort: $scope.sortChoice},
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.rows = data.rows;
        $scope.columns = data.columns;
    });
}
```